# Update rect width when changing data size

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to implement this bar chart example https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/73dbb9d6a144476565386f48a2df2e3b. However, instead of having data for each month of the year, for 2021 I have data until the current month .i.e. August and for the previous years I have data for all of the months. When I trigger the update function by selecting a year, the bar width is not updated (see picture below).

[image]

[image]
[image]

I tried to play a bit with the x domain function but I wasn't successful. Any hint would be appreciated.

Here is plnkr with a reproduction of my issue (Please click on the preview button and change the year to reproduce the problem):

https://plnkr.co/edit/kou3SFerDMTeKkkM?open=lib%2Fscript.js

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>   
<style>

body {
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 650px;
    font: 18px arial;
}   

</style>
</head>

<body>

<b>Dynamic bar-chart example.</b>
<svg id="chart" width="650" height="420"></svg>

Choose year: 
<select id="year"></select>

<input type="checkbox" id="sort">   
Toggle sort 

<script>

d3.csv("data.csv").then(d => chart(d));

function chart(csv) {

    csv.forEach(function(d) {
        var dates = d.date.split("-");
        d.year = dates[0]; d.month = dates[1];
        d.value = +d.value;
        return d;
    })

    var months = [...new Set(csv.map(d => d.month))],
        years  = [...new Set(csv.map(d => d.year))];

    var options = d3.select("#year").selectAll("option")
        .data(years)
    .enter().append("option")
        .text(d => d)

    var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
        margin = {top: 25, bottom: 10, left: 25, right: 25},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
        .padding(0.1)
        .paddingOuter(0.2)
    
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

    var xAxis = g => g
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

    var yAxis = g => g
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")

    update(d3.select("#year").property("value"), 0)

    function update(year, speed) {

        var data = csv.filter(f => f.year == year)
    
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()

        svg.selectAll(".y-axis").transition().duration(speed)
            .call(yAxis);

        data.sort(d3.select("#sort").property("checked")
            ? (a, b) => b.value - a.value
            : (a, b) => months.indexOf(a.month) - months.indexOf(b.month))

        x.domain(data.map(d => d.month))

        svg.selectAll(".x-axis").transition().duration(speed)
            .call(xAxis)

        var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data, d => d.month)

        bar.exit().remove();

        bar.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .merge(bar)
        .transition().duration(speed)
            .attr("x", d => x(d.month))
            .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
            .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.value))
    }

    chart.update = update;
}

var select = d3.select("#year")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .on("change", function() {
        chart.update(this.value, 750)
    })

var checkbox = d3.select("#sort")
    .style("margin-left", "45%")
    .on("click", function() {
        chart.update(select.property("value"), 750)
    })

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you have:

```
bar.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .merge(bar)
  .transition().duration(speed)
    .attr("x", d => x(d.month))
    .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
    .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.value))
```

You are only setting the width of the new rectangles. There are more months in the dataset for 2019 than 2018, so `x.bandwidth()` is smaller for 2019 than for 2018. This means that you need to update the width of the existing rectangles too. So you just need to move the line that updates the width to after the merge:

```
bar.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .merge(bar)
  .transition().duration(speed)
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", d => x(d.month))
    .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
    .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.value))
```

Also, I'd recommend checking out [join](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/main/README.md#selection_join) rather than using enter/merge/exit. It's easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you Dan, I really appreciate your explanation.